# Rails 4 Tagging users on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tags

Whats the best method on tagging users? If you have a team model, and when you create a team, you want to add the members, how would this architecture work?

I was thinking of just using acts as tanggble and use it on the users, but not sure if this would be the best method? Is there another gem out there that would do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a `has many through` relationship. This would require you to have a joining table called `team_members` to record which users are members of each team, having `user_id` and `team_id` columns. So for example your Team model would have a relationship that looks like this:

```
has_many :users, through: :team_members
```

This then defines the appropriate method on Team for adding, querying and removing users.

More information is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: What about nested attributes? Would this method work too?

Comment: Yes you can have nested attributes for both the User and the joining model. Check out [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) if you're struggling

Answer (score 0):

To add to `@tpbowden`'s answer, if you just want to "tag" users, you may wish to use [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

# join table "teams_users" - team_id | user_id

# app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to use the [`singular_collection_ids`](https://ernie.io/2010/10/02/the-underused-collection_singular_ids-method/) method, with which you'll be able to define which user is in a "team":

```
#app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   def edit
     @team = Team.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
     @team = Team.find params[:id]
     @team.update team_params
   end

   private

   def team_params
     params.require(:team).permit(user_ids: [])
   end
end

#app/views/teams/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is as close to "tagging" as you're going to get without any extra dependencies.

Comment: Would nested attributes work too? What would be the difference?

Comment: In the context of this answer's code, `nested_attributes` would only be required if you wanted to *create* a `group` / `user` as an associative object. If you wanted to just assign users to existing groups, the above will be sufficient